# SQL Developer Query returning blank output

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to only see all records that are in position "substr(B.GLDEBITACCT,24,8)" from the string below

```
            'FDN-XXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXX-XXTXXXXX-0000-0000'
```

So in my query displayed below, I chose to specifically pull in all records by the letter 'T' so I wrote the syntax as AND SUBSTR(M.GLDEBITACCT,24,8) = 'T'. Now this is giving me a blank output. Can someone help me decipher what I am not doing right here? I hope my question is succinct enough.

```
SELECT    
SUBSTR(M.GLDEBITACCT,24,8) as PROJECT,  
G.COMPTEXT AS PROJECT_NAME,  
' ' PROJECT_LEADER,  
TO_CHAR(W.EX2DERNUM) AS DERNUM,  
' ' AS DERLINENUM,  
' ' AS REQUESTNUM,   
M.REFWO AS WONUM,   
W.PARENT AS PARENT_WONUM,   
' ' AS PRNUM,  
' ' AS PRLINENUM,  
' ' AS PR_STATUS,  
TO_CHAR(M.PONUM) AS PO_NUMBER,              
TO_CHAR(M.POLINENUM) AS POLINE_NUMBER,  
' ' AS PO_STATUS,  
' ' AS PO_REVISIONNUM, 
' ' AS PO_VENDOR_NUM,
' ' AS VENDOR,  
M.ITEMNUM,  
M.DESCRIPTION,  
I.ISSUEUNIT AS UOM,  
TO_CHAR(M.QTYREQUESTED) AS WO_QTY_REQ,  
TO_CHAR(M.QUANTITY) AS WO_QTY_RECEIVED,  
TO_CHAR(M.UNITCOST) AS WO_UNITCOST,  
TO_CHAR(M.LINECOST) AS WO_LINECOST,  
M.ISSUETYPE,  
TO_CHAR(M.ACTUALDATE) AS ISSUEDATE,  
W.STATUS AS WONUM_STATUS,  
' ' AS PR_QTY_REQ,  
' ' AS PO_QTY_REQ,
' ' AS ACTUAL_QTY_RECEIVED,
' ' AS PO_QTY_RECEIVED,  
' ' AS PO_QTY_OPEN,  
' ' AS PO_UNITCOST,  
' ' AS PO_LINECOST,  
' ' AS SHIPTO,  
' ' AS DROP_SHIP,  
' ' AS ENTERDATE,  
' ' AS REQDELIVERYDATE,  
' ' AS VENDELIVERYDATE,  
' ' AS STATUSDATE, 
' ' AS RECEIPTDATE,
' ' AS DIRECT_CHARGE,
' ' AS VENDROR_COMMENT  


FROM MSCRADS.MATUSETRANS M
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
MXRADS.WORKORDER W ON
M.REFWO = W.WONUM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN             
MXRADS.ITEM I ON
M.ITEMNUM = I.ITEMNUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN
MXRADS.VW_GLCOMPONENTS G
ON SUBSTR(M.GLDEBITACCT,24,8) = G.COMPVALUE

WHERE M.ISSUETYPE IN ('ISSUE','RETURN')              
AND M.SITEID = 'FDN'  
AND M.PONUM IS NULL
AND M.ACTUALDATE >= TO_DATE('2014-05-26','YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND SUBSTR(M.GLDEBITACCT,24,8) = 'T'
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Re-tagged with `oracle` because the syntax is clearly Oracle and "SQL Developer" also suggests Oracle.

Comment: Pardon me, I see what you mean. I query the ORACLE DATABASE (ODS) and "SUBSTR" works for me.

Comment: this looks like it may be Oracle and not SQL-Server ... but anyhow, you are looking for matching records that have 8 characters equal to a single character, 'T'.  That's not going to find any matches.

Comment: @BWS yes it is ORACLE. Initially, I sort of hardcoded my query to leave all records that do not have the 'T' but there are alot that do not have the 'T'. So I am wondering how to code the query to only pull in the string with the 'T' in the position I stated in my question.

Comment: Change 'AND SUBSTR(M.GLDEBITACCT,24,8) = 'T'' to 'AND SUBSTR(M.GLDEBITACCT,24,1) = 'T'' ... to match on just the one character at position 24.

Comment: @BWS, thanks for  your input. Yes I changed 'AND SUBSTR(M.GLDEBITACCT,24,8) = 'T' to 'AND SUBSTR(M.GLDEBITACCT,26,1) = 'T' and got the records I want to see. Thank you once more.